A basic problem of projecting 3D point in world space to 2D pixel in image space with Panda3D
I have been confused for this problem for a long time.
How do I get exact pixel position in window client area which is projected from a 3D point in a model loaded by Panda3D with OrthographicLens?
Here is my model loading and camera setting code (ignore trivial flaws). Now I have a 3D point (-0.2, 0.21, 0.5). What is its exact coordinates of pixel on a screen window in OrthographicLens?
class PandaShotMachine(ShowBase):

def __init__(self):
    ShowBase.__init__(self)

        self.windowhalfedge=768
        self.openDefaultWindow(size=[self.windowhalfedge,self.windowhalfedge]);
        base.disableMouse()
    
        self.running=True

    def LoadAndConfigModel(self, filepath: str):
        self.setBackgroundColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)

        winfile=filepath
        pandafile = Filename.fromOsSpecific(winfile)
    
        # Load the environment model.
        self.scene = self.loader.loadModel(pandafile, noCache=True)        

        self.SetCameraAndLight(0.0, False, False);

        # Reparent the model to render.
        self.scene.reparentTo(self.render)

    def SetCameraAndLight(self, centerrotateangle: float, isconceptual: bool, perspective: bool):
        c=self.scene.getBounds().getCenter()
        r=self.scene.getBounds().getRadius()
        edge=self.scene.getTightBounds()[1][0]-self.scene.getTightBounds()[0][0]
        if edge<self.scene.getTightBounds()[1][2]-self.scene.getTightBounds()[0][2]:
            edge=self.scene.getTightBounds()[1][2]-self.scene.getTightBounds()[0][2]
        height=self.scene.getTightBounds()[1][1]-self.scene.getTightBounds()[0][1]
        focus=c
        eyepos=LVector3f(c[0]+r,c[1]+r,c[2]+r)
        filmedge=r
        lightmag=0.1
        #print([edge, height])
        if edge*2<height:
            if perspective:
                focus=LVector3f(c[0],self.scene.getTightBounds()[1][1]-edge,c[2])
                filmedge=height-edge/1.414
            er=log(height/edge/2)+1
            eyepos=LVector3f(focus[0]+edge*er,focus[1]+edge*er,focus[2]+edge*er)
            lightmag=0.2

        cr=eyepos[0]-focus[0]
        eyepos=LVector3f(focus[0]+cr*cos(centerrotateangle*pi/180), focus[1]+cr, focus[2]+cr*sin(centerrotateangle*pi/180))

        #self.scene.showTightBounds()
        #self.scene.showBounds()

        if perspective:
            lens = PerspectiveLens()
            lens.setFov(60)
            lens.setViewVector(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0)
            base.cam.node().setLens(lens)
        else:
            lens = OrthographicLens()
            lens.setFar(1.732*2*r)
            lens.setNear(0.0)
            lens.setViewVector(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0)
            lens.setFilmSize(2*filmedge, 2*filmedge)  # Or whatever is appropriate for your scene            
            base.cam.node().setLens(lens)

        self.camera.setPos(eyepos)
        self.camera.lookAt(focus, LVector3f(0.0,1.0,0.0))
        hpr=self.camera.getHpr()#！！！！
        self.projectfocus=focus
        self.projectcameraplanecenter=eyepos
        self.projecthalfedge=filmedge

if name == ‘main’:
try:
winfile = u’D:/MultiWheel_HATS.obj’

    app = PandaShotMachine()
    app.LoadAndConfigModel(winfile)
    app.SetCameraAndLight(60.0, False, False)

    while app.running:
        if not app.win.getProperties().getOpen():
            app.running=False
            break
        app.taskMgr.step()

    app.destroy()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

I have tried many methods, e.g., using invertFrom(cameraToWorld) matrix, etc. The consequence is apparently wrong.
I want to know the steps of getting 2D coordinates of the pixel of showing window projected from 3D point with Panda3D (python interface) in OrthographicLens. For such window client area, left-upper corner means origin (0,0).
